# Advanced HTML/CSS serious bug

Tags: html, css, web

Link to the example stated:

https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-2/hw2html.html

I'm hoping you are able to solve this problem as both my professor and I couldn't figure it out. I'm taking CIS122 in college, this is my Homework-2 assignment. I finished all the requirements for the assignment and now I'm just working on the extra credit, I've done most of the work, the problem is a bug that I keep running into. Let me explain:

When you run the code into a browser (I use google chrome) the page pops up, in the nav section you see my previous assignment and a link to the current assignment I'm doing. Obviously, this is just a navigator to my other homework and I'll update it with my future homework. But when you hover over "Client Server" the .hover doesn't work as it does with the "Hosting Domain" hover.

It's supposed to turn dark red with ivory colored letters but it doesn't work. Sometimes when you readjust the browser it allows you to click the .hover if you click in the bottom center sweet spot. So this was causing me a giant issue so I decided to leave it alone and try working on something else. I started working on my "Profile" link and I added a line of code, I added [ float:right; ] just so my profile tab would work better. I added this line to code to the following:

```
aside ul li {
display:inline-block;
background-color: grey;
float:right;
}
```

So when I added this line of code float:right; I realized that the "Profile" bar is now hugging the right side which is what I wanted but now when I hovered over "Profiles" the GitHub/Sololearn bar overlapped over the profiles tab and this caused more frustration, but I noticed that now when I hovered over the Client Server tab in the nav, it worked just fine and the Darkred background and ivory letters worked again like normal, so this simple line of code float:right fixed my nav tab which is great but now overlapped onto my "Profile" tab in the aside section, does somebody have an idea on how I am able to fix both issues, I need my "Client Server" tab in the nav to work as it's part of the extra credit, but I also want my Profile tab to work as I need a profile tab also?

(An about section which I picked profile) I don't think this is a easy fix like most of my other questions are, my professor couldn't figure it out either, granted he only looked for around 5 minutes but no matter what I do this bug is causing me frustration and I've tried just about everything, other students didn't do as much so I don't have other work to base it off of, I know a dedicated programmer out there can figure this out but right now I'm clueless.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Homework #2: HTML, CSS, Semantic and Responsive Page Layout,     Domain                     Names, and Web Hosting</title>
<meta name="description" content="Homework #1: HTML and Client-Server Technology">
<meta name="keywords" content="technology, HTML, CSS, server, client">
<meta name="author" content="Joe Cline">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hw2style.css"> 
</head>
<body> 
<header>
<h1 id="CIS">CIS 122 Projects</h1>
</header>

<!--
metatags-noindex robots.txt
-->

<nav id="nav" style="background:black;">
    <div class="navbase">
        <a href="https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-1/HTML-        1.html">Client Server</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbase1">
        <a href="https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-    2/hw2html.html">Hosting Domain</a>
    </div>
</nav>

<section>
    <h2 id="DN">Domain Names and Web Hosting</h2>
    <h3 id="WDN"></h3>
    <table align="center" border="3">
        <tr>
            <th><a href="https://www.godaddy.com/" id="GD">GoDaddy</a></th>
            <th><a href="https://www.hostgator.com/" id="HG">HostGator</a>    </th>
            <th><a href="https://www.namecheap.com/" id="NC">NameCheap</a>    </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="GDtd">GoDaddy is a domain registrar and web hosting service, known for their cheap domain names and their web hosting service that they offer.</td>
            <td id="HGtd">HostGator is a web hosting service and provider of shared, reseller, vps. They include all of the following: Cloud Hosting/WordPress Hosting/VPS Hosting/Dedicated Hosting.</td>
            <td id="NCtd">NameCheap is an ICANN-accredited registrar, they provide domain name registration and web hosting.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="price">If your interested in buying a .com web domain from GoDaddy, the prices are the following: For 5 years it would cost you $62.95, the price is $2.99 for the first year and $14.99 for every year after that.</p>
    <p id="musicsale">The domain name musicsales.com was bought using the service: Network Solutions, LLC. The domain name expires on 2021-08-24 </p>
    <p id="musicsaleinfo">If you want to buy the domain name musicsales.info it could cost you around $4.88, some websites like GoDaddy/NameCheap charges cheaper but they force you to get a plan </p>

    <table align="center" border="3" id="TLD">
        <caption class="title" id="title1"> <b>Newer TLDs of 2018</b>
        <tr>
            <td>.basketball</td>
            <td>.book</td>
            <td>.luxe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>.fan</td>
            <td>.arab</td>
            <td>.broker</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>.hotel</td>
            <td>.phd</td>
            <td>.scholarships</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="bluehost">Webhosting at Bluehost.com will cost around $2.95/month*, this could vary though. The orginal starting price was $7.99, this changed to $3.95 and then changed again to it's final price of $2.95/month* </p>

    <ol id="list-1"> 
        <li><p id="list1">Test </p></li>
        <li><p id="list2">Test </p></li>
        <li><p id="list3">Test </p></li>
    </ol>
    <ul id="list-2">
        <li><p id="list4">Test </p></li>
        <li><p id="list5">Test </p></li>
        <li><p id="list6">Test </p></li>
    </ul>
    <ol id="list-3">
        <li><p id="list7">Test </p></li>
        <li><p id="list8">Test </p></li>
        <li><p id="list9">Test </p></li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="list-4">
        <li><p id="list10">Test </p></li>
        <li><p id="list11">Test </p></li>
        <li><p id="list12">Test </p></li>
    </ol> 

</section>

<aside>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Profiles</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Profile/2260402#_=_">Sololearn</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/JosephCline">GitHub</a></li>
        </ul>
</aside>

<footer>
    <sub id="sub">CIS 122 Web Internet Technologies </sub>
    <br />
    <sub id="sub3">Copyright &copy; 2018 Joe Cline </sub>
</footer>
```

```
body {
margin: 0;
color: #000;
background: Ivory;
font-family:Andale Mono, monospace;
}
#CIS {
margin:0;
font-weight:500;
border:darkred solid;
border-radius: 25px;
font-family:Andale Mono,monospace;
}
header {
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 16px;
}
footer {
clear: both;
padding: 16px;
background-color: #000;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, 
}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 480px)
and (min-width: 700px)    
{
section {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
}


.navbase1 {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: grey;
}
.navbase1 a  {
float: left;
display:block;
color: black;
text-align:center;
padding: 15px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
}
.navbase1 a:hover {
background-color: darkred;
color:Ivory;
}    

.navbase {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: grey;
}
.navbase a {
float: left;
display:block;
color: black;
text-align:center;
padding: 15px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
}
.navbase a:hover {
background-color: darkred;
color:Ivory;
}

#sub {
color:Ivory;
font-size:12px;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
#sub3 {
color:Ivory;
font-weight:900;
font-size:12px;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
#DN {
text-align:center;
}
#PDN {
text-align:center;
}
tr, td, th { 
padding: 20px; 
border: solid 5px black;
text-align: center;
background:Ivory;
font-family:Andale Mono, monospace;
}
table {
border:none;
}
#GD {
color:darkred;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:20px;
}
#HG {
color:darkred;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:20px;
}
#NC {
color:darkred;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:20px;
}
#price {
border-radius: 25px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 20px; 
}
#TLD {
padding: 20px; 
text-align: center;
background:Ivory;
font-family:Andale Mono, monospace;
}
h3 {
text-align:center;
}
#musicsale {
border-radius: 25px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 20px;
}
#musicsaleinfo {
border-radius: 25px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 20px;
}
#bluehost {
border-radius: 25px;
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 20px;
}
#list-1 {
width:320px;
font-style:italic;
font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;
font-size:24px; 
color:darkred;
display:block;
}
#list-2 {
width:320px;
font-style:italic;
font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;
font-size:24px;
color:darkred;
display:block;
}
#list-3 {
width:320px;
font-style:italic;
font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;
font-size:24px; 
color:darkred;
display:block;
}
#list-4 {
width:320px;
font-style:italic;
font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;
font-size:24px; 
color:darkred;  
display:block;
}
ul {
list-style-type: square;
}
ol {
list-style-type: decimal;
}
#list1{
font-size:15px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
display:block;
padding:8px;
}
#list2{
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list3{
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list4 {
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list5 { 
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list6 {
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list7 { 
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list8 {
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list9 {
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list10 {
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list11 {
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}
#list12 {
font-size:15px;
display:block;
padding:8px;
border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

aside ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}
aside ul li {
display:inline-block;
background-color: grey;    
}
aside a {
display:block;
padding:0 80;
color:Black;
font-size:20px;
line-height: 60px;
text-decoration:none;
}

aside a:hover {
background-color:darkred;
color:Ivory;
}
aside ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
}
aside ul li:hover > ul {
display:inherit;
}
aside ul ul li {
min-width:170px;
display:list-item;
position: relative;
}
#title1 {
height:1px;
}
#GDtd {
color:darkred;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
}
#HGtd {
color:darkred;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
}
#NCtd {
color:darkred;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px;
}
#WDN {
height:2px;
font-size:20px;
}
```

### Update

Thank you, everybody, for helping me solve my issue, I finally got an answer that helped me solve my issue. It was so stupid and simple and I deeply appreciate all of you guys for answering my post but also viewing it so it was able to get solved.

Comment: Guys, I seriously need help with this. My previous post got revised but not answered. If somebody could please at least give an idea about what is wrong with it so I can research it myself that would be great. I don't need an answer even though it would help greatly, I just need tips or at least to know what the problem is so I can research how to solve it. Please don't just downvote because when you do, nobody sees it after like 20 views and I feel like this is a seriously challenging question.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Which is the relevant part of the code? What is the behavior you are getting vs what you are expecting?

Comment: The problem was solved using the code 

aside {
  float: left;
  width:15%;
}

It seems so simple but I've been working on this for hours and didn't realize it, the problem was that when I hovered over Client/Server box it wasn't working.  When I did something else recommended from another member it solved the issue of the hover box but caused another issue which was whenever I hovered over the Profile tag it now displayed far down the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `<ul>` element sits **on top** of your `Client Server` tab, but **not** your `Hosting Domain` tab. That is why the latter can be hovered over, and the former cannot (you'll be hovering over the `<ul>` instead. You'll notice that when you hover over the bottom of `Client Server` the effect gets applied -- this is because the `<ul>` doesn't completely overlap it.

To correct this, simply remove `position: relative` from your `aside ul`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

#CIS {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: darkred solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget,
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (min-width: 700px) {
  section {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
  }
  nav {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
  }
}

.navbase1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.navbase1 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbase1 a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
}

.navbase {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.navbase a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbase a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
}

#sub {
  color: Ivory;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#sub3 {
  color: Ivory;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

#DN {
  text-align: center;
}

#PDN {
  text-align: center;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 5px black;
  text-align: center;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

table {
  border: none;
}

#GD {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#HG {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#NC {
  color: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#price {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#TLD {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: Ivory;
  font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#musicsale {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#musicsaleinfo {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#bluehost {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#list-1 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-2 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-3 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

#list-4 {
  width: 320px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: darkred;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

#list1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}

#list2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list6 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list7 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list8 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list9 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list10 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list11 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

#list12 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid darkred;
}

aside ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

aside ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
}

aside a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 80;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

aside a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  color: Ivory;
}

aside ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

aside ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

aside ul ul li {
  min-width: 170px;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

#title1 {
  height: 1px;
}

#GDtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#HGtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#NCtd {
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#WDN {
  height: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Homework #2: HTML, CSS, Semantic and Responsive Page Layout, Domain Names, and Web Hosting</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Homework #1: HTML and Client-Server Technology">
  <meta name="keywords" content="technology, HTML, CSS, server, client">
  <meta name="author" content="Joe Cline">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hw2style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="CIS">CIS 122 Projects</h1>
  </header>

  <!--
metatags-noindex robots.txt
-->

  <nav id="nav" style="background:black;">
    <div class="navbase">
      <a href="https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-1/HTML-        1.html">Client Server</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbase1">
      <a href="https://cislinux.hfcc.edu/~jdcline/cis122/homework-    2/hw2html.html">Hosting Domain</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section>
    <h2 id="DN">Domain Names and Web Hosting</h2>
    <h3 id="WDN"></h3>
    <table align="center" border="3">
      <tr>
        <th><a href="https://www.godaddy.com/" id="GD">GoDaddy</a></th>
        <th><a href="https://www.hostgator.com/" id="HG">HostGator</a> </th>
        <th><a href="https://www.namecheap.com/" id="NC">NameCheap</a> </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="GDtd">GoDaddy is a domain registrar and web hosting service, known for their cheap domain names and their web hosting service that they offer.</td>
        <td id="HGtd">HostGator is a web hosting service and provider of shared, reseller, vps. They include all of the following: Cloud Hosting/WordPress Hosting/VPS Hosting/Dedicated Hosting.</td>
        <td id="NCtd">NameCheap is an ICANN-accredited registrar, they provide domain name registration and web hosting.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="price">If your interested in buying a .com web domain from GoDaddy, the prices are the following: For 5 years it would cost you $62.95, the price is $2.99 for the first year and $14.99 for every year after that.</p>
    <p id="musicsale">The domain name musicsales.com was bought using the service: Network Solutions, LLC. The domain name expires on 2021-08-24 </p>
    <p id="musicsaleinfo">If you want to buy the domain name musicsales.info it could cost you around $4.88, some websites like GoDaddy/NameCheap charges cheaper but they force you to get a plan </p>

    <table align="center" border="3" id="TLD">
      <caption class="title" id="title1"> <b>Newer TLDs of 2018</b>
        <tr>
          <td>.basketball</td>
          <td>.book</td>
          <td>.luxe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>.fan</td>
          <td>.arab</td>
          <td>.broker</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>.hotel</td>
          <td>.phd</td>
          <td>.scholarships</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="bluehost">Webhosting at Bluehost.com will cost around $2.95/month*, this could vary though. The orginal starting price was $7.99, this changed to $3.95 and then changed again to it's final price of $2.95/month* </p>

    <ol id="list-1">
      <li>
        <p id="list1">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list2">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list3">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ul id="list-2">
      <li>
        <p id="list4">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list5">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list6">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ol id="list-3">
      <li>
        <p id="list7">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list8">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list9">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="list-4">
      <li>
        <p id="list10">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list11">Test </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p id="list12">Test </p>
      </li>
    </ol>

  </section>

  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Profiles</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Profile/2260402#_=_">Sololearn</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://github.com/JosephCline">GitHub</a></li>
        </ul>
  </aside>

  <footer>
    <sub id="sub">CIS 122 Web Internet Technologies </sub>
    <br />
    <sub id="sub3">Copyright &copy; 2018 Joe Cline </sub>
  </footer>
```

You also have invalid markup (you're missing the closing `</caption>` in your table, and the closing `</li></ul>` in your `<aside>`), though this is not responsible for your problem. It may pay to run your code through a validator like **[W3C](https://validator.w3.org)** though :)

As an aside, I wouldn't consider this 'advanced' by any means -- it both shocks and saddens me to hear that your university professor was unable to diagnose this issue.

Comment: Getting rid of position: relative from aside ul fixes the hover issue but now when I hover over profiles there is a large difference between the "Profile" tab and the "GitHub" "Sololearn". also I don't see the problem of <ul> sitting on top of the client-server tab? could you point this out so I can fix it?

Comment: Obsidian Age I would appreciate deeply if you could come back and further explain, I printed out my code and tried looking at what you were doing and I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Start by fixing your HTML

Look at this:

```
<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Profiles</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Profile/2260402#_=_">Sololearn</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/JosephCline">GitHub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li><!-- MISSING -->
  </ul><!-- MISSING -->
</aside>
```

...

Here's the solution:

```
aside {
  float: left;
  width:15%;
}
```

Comment: I see that I forgot to add the ending tag, also I haven't focused on any other validation as I'm currently trying to solve the current bug. Do you have any tips or ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: @Joe, bad HTML sometimes produces unpredictable CSS and javascript behavior. If you have the correct HTML code, post it here.

Comment: Here is a link to the Tryit Editor, I really cannot figure out this bug. ObsidianAge gave me some tips and I applied them but it caused another problem. Now I can hover over my Two nav links but when I hover over my Profiles tag it displays my Github/Sololearn link but its not under the Profile tag like it was before, now its displayed way under the profile tab and now I have another bug that I don't understand. I'm currently plugging my code into the W3 validator but I don't believe it will solve my issue. 

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVFTHR4I5PSY

Comment: You have 3 main columns: nav, section, and aside. Only nav and section have a width and are floated to the left. The problem you have is that aside extends throughout the entire screen covering the first item of your nav. See my edited solution.

Comment: Thank you, it finally worked. I deeply appreciate this, you didn't have to take the time out of your day to look at my code but you did so I deeply appreciate and thank you.